# Windows Azure Web App - Schedule Application Pool Recycle

Tags: azure

I have a Windows Azure Web App.

I need to adjust the Application pool recycle so that it occurs every day at 03:00 uk time rather than the default 29 hours.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can this be done using  WebJob https://knowledge-base.havit.eu/2018/07/31/azure-app-service-scheduled-restart/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) create file named: **applicationHost.xdt**

2) insert override for the pool recycling time i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <applicationPools>
      <add name="yourappname" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <recycling xdt:Transform="Insert" >
          <periodicRestart>
            <schedule>
              <clear />
              <add value="03:00:00" />  // + adjust for server time/ UTC
            </schedule>
          </periodicRestart>
        </recycling>
      </add>
    </applicationPools>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

3) upload the file into your app /site root:

[image]

4) Hard stop and start your service/app (restart will not take effect!)

5) You may [check this resource](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#remove-all-your-recycling-options-from-your-net-4-application-pool-and-make-it-available-always) for more info on .xdt file

Comment: For those finding this, this solution no longer works as Microsoft has made changes to DWAS and the settings will not be honored.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to schedule the recycle, then, if the above solution doesn't work?

Comment: FYI, I have just received confirmation from Microsoft that this is not possible, via the portal, the method above or by any other means.